# Linear actuator calculations

Tags: actuator, linear-motion

I'm building a motorized standing desk and am looking into what to use for the linear actuators. I'm targeting a stroke of 450mm and a lifting force of 100kg. I found some [Linear Actuator](https://www.ebay.com/itm/2-18-Inch-Stroke-Linear-Actuator-1500N-330lbs-Pound-Max-Lift-12V-Volt-DC-Motor/112887896341?hash=item1a48a49915:m:mdfXAjchkXMgJEmUIpXpOCQ:rk:3:pf:0) on ebay that would work but I was wondering if I could go cheaper.

If I'm using this [calculator](https://www.daycounter.com/Calculators/Lead-Screw-Force-Torque-Calculator.phtml) right then a for lead screw with 2mm pitch and 8mm diameter to lift 100kg I need a torque of ~114 N*cm.

I think this [lead screw](https://www.aliexpress.com/item/RepRap-3D-Printer-THSL-300-8D-Lead-Screw-Dia-8MM-Thread-8mm-Length-300mm-with-Copper/32435304660.html?spm=2114.search0104.3.9.359b61c3w8Ukqd&ws_ab_test=searchweb0_0,searchweb201602_5_10065_10068_10130_10890_5730315_10547_319_10546_317_10548_10545_10696_453_10084_454_10083_10618_5729215_10307_538_537_536_10059_10884_10887_100031_321_322_10103,searchweb201603_51,ppcSwitch_0&algo_expid=db65bc82-a987-45fb-84de-8a7e6f34e441-1&algo_pvid=db65bc82-a987-45fb-84de-8a7e6f34e441) and a [Nema 23](https://www.aliexpress.com/item/NEMA23-stepper-motor-57X56mm-3-0A1-8-Degree-stepping-motor-175Oz-in-Nema-23-CNC-for/32951270990.html?spm=2114.search0104.3.7.e1ac68c00GHjot&ws_ab_test=searchweb0_0,searchweb201602_5_10065_10068_10130_10890_5730315_10547_319_10546_317_10548_10545_10696_453_10084_454_10083_5729211_10618_10307_538_537_536_10059_10884_10887_100031_321_322_10103,searchweb201603_51,ppcSwitch_0&algo_expid=7ca8b519-e947-4831-bdfb-a8e78c4859f1-4&algo_pvid=7ca8b519-e947-4831-bdfb-a8e78c4859f1) should work. Together that's half the price of the linear actuator.

Is that right? I don't have much experience and could easily be missing something obvious.

Comment: So why change from cm and kg to oz and inches?

Comment: The motors I was looking at were oz*in